# bootstrap-table.js how to remove row within actionevent

Tags: bootstrap-table

How do I change the 'alert' click event in this fiddle to remove the row in which the icon was clicked?  I have tried several approaches none of which have worked.  I want to delete/remove the row, not post an alert.  Thank you in advance.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/39/)

```
        function actionFormatter(value, row, index) {
        return [
    '<a class="like" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Like">',
    '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>',
    '</a>',
    '<a class="edit ml10" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit">',
    '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>',
    '</a>',
    '<a class="remove ml10" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Remove">',
    '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>',
    '</a>'
       ].join('');
          }

   window.actionEvents = {
     'click .like': function (e, value, row, index) {
    alert('You click like icon, row: ' + JSON.stringify(row));
    console.log(value, row, index);
},
'click .edit': function (e, value, row, index) {
    alert('You click edit icon, row: ' + JSON.stringify(row));
    console.log(value, row, index);
},
'click .remove': function (e, value, row, index) {
    alert('You click remove icon, row: ' + JSON.stringify(row));
    console.log(value, row, index);
     }
      };
```

Comment: in the documentation [link](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/index.html#methods/remove.html)  If I were using checkboxes, it would need to get the row id of the checkbox then $table.bootstrapTable('remove', {field: 'id', values: ids});  But in this case, it's an icon event within the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added:   var    $table = $('#table')

and this to the click function:
  'click .remove': function (e, value, row, index) {
                   $table.bootstrapTable('remove', {
                    field: 'id',
                    values: [row.id]
                });

Now it works.

```
      var   $table = $('#table')

 function actionFormatter(value, row, index) {
    return [
'<a class="like" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Like">',
'<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>',
'</a>',
'<a class="edit ml10" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit">',
'<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>',
'</a>',
'<a class="remove ml10" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Remove">',
'<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>',
'</a>'
   ].join('');
      }

   window.actionEvents = {
     'click .like': function (e, value, row, index) {
    alert('You click like icon, row: ' + JSON.stringify(row));
    console.log(value, row, index);
},
'click .edit': function (e, value, row, index) {
    alert('You click edit icon, row: ' + JSON.stringify(row));
    console.log(value, row, index);
},
    'click .remove': function (e, value, row, index) {
               $table.bootstrapTable('remove', {
                field: 'id',
                values: [row.id]
            });
    }
};
```